# Opera's Dragonfly generate xpath

Tags: xpath, automation, css-selectors, firebug, opera

I'm an automated QA tester and I recently discovered the power of Dragonfly, the developer plugin for Opera. It's a really great tool, however I cannot find any information about Dragonfly's ability to generate either xpath queries or css selectors. Both of these are very useful for web automation. I'm currently using Firebug which works great. However I'm always looking for the next best tool and I would love to learn more about Dragonfly.

Does anyone know if Dragonfly has the ability to at least generate Xpath queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wondering the same thing last year, and a member of the Dragonfly team said [it was planned](http://my.opera.com/dragonfly/blog/show.dml/35535932#comment70628402), but it couldn't be implemented until the Clipboard API was supported in Opera. The Clipboard API was added to Opera in [Presto 2.10](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto2.10/#m210-294). Consequently, I suspect that we will be seeing this feature added to Dragonfly sometime in the near future.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'll take this as a 'No'. I guess we'll just keep waiting until they implement it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with generating *CSS selector*, then there is an easy tip for you.

Click 'Inspect element', go to Layout tab in side menu of Document tab, and there you will see something like this:
`html > body.question-page > div.container > div#content > div > div#mainbar > div#question.question > table > tbody > tr > td.postcell > div > div.post-text > p`

---

offtopic: *neither xpath, nor css selectors are hard to learn, and both are much better written manually, then they are generated.*